# message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime with PointCloud and custom message not working

Tags: message-filters, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to sync and process a topic with PointCloud messages together with a self created message type called *IntList*, which contains a Header field with timestamps and a data field (int32[ ]) with RGB image coordinates from which I want to extract PointCloud information) published by another topic ().
For this I want to use the message_filters package with the ApproximateTime policy.

Here is my node (which I created based on the instructions [here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters?distro=kinetic#ApproximateTime_Policy)):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <image_processing/IntList.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
typedef image_processing::IntList IntList;

using namespace message_filters;

void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& pclMsg, const image_processing::IntList::ConstPtr& coordsMsg)
{
 //Do something with the coordinates 
 ROS_INFO("Recieved coordinates: (%d,%d) ", coordsMsg->data[0], coordsMsg->data[1]);

 //Do something with the point cloud
 ROS_INFO("Cloud width: %d, cloud height: %d", pclMsg->width, pclMsg-->height);

 //Do something more
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 printf("sync node main started");
 ros::init(argc, argv, "world_coords_extraction");
 ros::NodeHandle nh;

 message_filters::Subscriber<PointCloud> pcl_sub(nh, "/camera/depth_registered/points", 1);
 message_filters::Subscriber<IntList> coords_sub(nh, "/detected_coordinates", 1);

 typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<PointCloud, IntList> MySyncPolicy;

 Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(100), pcl_sub, coords_sub);

 sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2));
 
 ros::spin();

 return 0;
}
```

I have tested this scenario with topics published by a rosbag file. I looked at the timestamps and they are more than a bit apart, so I increased the queue size parameter of the synchronizer (*sync(MySyncPolicy(100), ... ))*.
**But** --> as you can see, I added a simple *printf* at the beginning of the main. When starting the node, not even this printf is displayed on the console, so there must be another problem before the message_filter code is reached, right?

Just to ensure the  the general functionality of the published topics and the subscription to these topics, I created single subscribers and callbacks for each of those topics, like this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub_coords = nh.subscribe("/detected_coordinates", 10, callback);
ros::Subscriber sub_pc = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, callback);
```

This is working fine.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong with the message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime code?

Thanks in advace.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258995/message_filters::sync_policies::approximatetime-with-pointcloud-and-custom-message-not-working/) by [UllusParvus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29586/ullusparvus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aihanbing](https://answers.ros.org/users/39206/aihanbing/) on 2019-01-08**:
hello, I also met the same situation, would you mind to share the solution? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Although I've not yet personally confirmed) [This thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/186935/approximatetime-policy-error/) seems to be talking about exactly the same issue and the solution is to use the right message type.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0